# Problema al mostrar los datos de una tabla en php, error en las rutas

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

tengo un problema y no se si es la ruta, o algún fallo de sintaxis, pero al leer el archivo leerRoles.php y que este me ejecute el select de la base de datos de los roles, me sale un error, les comento.

Tengo la siguiente estructura de carpetas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el archivo config.php tengo la configuración de las variables

```
            `<?php
             $servidor= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
             $path_actual=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
             $host="localhost"; 
             $dbname="clinicaveterinaria";
             $username="root";
             $password="";

             if(!defined('__CONFIG__')){
             define('__CONFIG__',true);
             define('ROOT_PATH',$servidor);
             define('RUTA_ACTUAL', $path_actual);
             define("HOST",$host);
             define("DB",$dbname);
             define("USUARIO",$username);
             define("CLAVE",$password);
            // define('CARPETA_ACTUAL',CARPETA_PADRE.basename(getcwd()).'/');
            }

            ?>`
```

Luego en conexion.php llama a las variables donde tengo definido el nombre de la BBDD, de la tabla, etc

```
           ´<?php
             //ACCEDEMOS A LA DEFINICION DE LAS VARIABLES QUE TENEMOS EN CONFIG.PHP 
            require_once("../../config/config.php");
            class ConexionBD{
            // protected $conexion;
            public function getConexion(){
            $conexion = null;
            try {
                    $conexion = new PDO(
                        'mysql:host='.HOST.
                        ';dbname='.DB.";charset=utf8",
                         USUARIO, 
                         CLAVE
                        );
            } catch (PDOException $e)  {
                   echo "No se ha podido conectar a la BBDD, causa PDOException: ".$e- 
            >getMessage();
                   exit;
            }
            return $conexion;      
            } 
           }´
```

En el modelo, en el archivo usuariosModelo.php, tengo  una función en la cual, debería de ejecutar una consulta

```
     `<?php
      require_once("./conexion.php");

      class UsuariosModelo{

      function obtenerRolesModelo(){
        $consulta = "SELECT * FROM ROLES";
        $conexion = new ConexionBD();
 
        $query = $conexion::conexionBD()->prepare($consulta);

        return $query->execute()->fetchAll();
        }
      }
       ?>`
```

Finalmente en el archivo leerRoles.

```
     ´<?php
      header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
      header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

      include_once '../modelo/usuariosModelo.php';

      $items = new UsuariosModelo();
      $stmt = $items->obtenerRolesModelo();
      echo $stmt;
      $itemCount = $stmt->rowCount();´
```

El error que me sale cuando voy a leer el archivo leerRoles.php es este:

**Warning**: require_once(./conexion.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in **C:\laragon\www\Repositorio\Clinica-Veterinaria\backend\crud\modelo\usuariosModelo.php** on line **2**
**Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Failed opening required './conexion.php' (include_path='.;C:/laragon/etc/php/pear') in C:\laragon\www\Repositorio\Clinica-Veterinaria\backend\crud\modelo\usuariosModelo.php:2Stack trace:#0 C:\laragon\www\Repositorio\Clinica-Veterinaria\backend\crud\api\leerRoles.php(5): include_once()#1 {main}thrown in **C:\laragon\www\Repositorio\Clinica-Veterinaria\backend\crud\modelo\usuariosModelo.php** on line **2**

Comment: `./` significa literalmente retroceder una carpeta. En tu caso,.saldría de la carpeta actual, que es `modelo`, yendo a `crud`, en la cual no hay un archivo llamado `conexion.php`. Además, ya que defines ciertas constantes, sería bueno que definas constantes directas para aquellos archivos que se usan mucho, como es la conexión a la BD.

Comment: Tal y como dice Cedano, la ruta no la estas entregando debidamente. Corrige eso y deberia funcionar.

Comment: si funciona pero cuando desde react hago el fetch de la ruta, no la encuentra xD